# Active Directory: New User Registration fails

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

when I try to add a new user to our Active Directory Server, the following error message appears:

> Windows cannot create the object because the Directory Service was unable to allocate a relative identifier.

What's the meaning of this error and how do I fix it?

I might add that although I'm a pretty experienced Unix user, I'm completely new to Windows, Active Directory and the like. Additionally, the problem above arose in my new employment, and I have not yet fully grasped the infrastructure over here. My current guess is that the error is due to the recent migration of all servers to VMWare HyperVisor.

Anyway, the event log of what I think is the Domain Controller contains the following error repeatedly:

> MessageId=6702
>
> Severity=Error
>
> SymbolicName=DNS_EVENT_UPDATE_DS_PEERS_FAILURE
>
> DNS Server has updated its own host (A) records. In order to insure that its DS-integrated peer DNS servers are able to replicate with this server, an attempt was made to update them with the new records through dynamic update. An error was encountered during this update, the record data is the error code.

I'd be glad to hear any suggestions/hints/comments on this. Otherwise, I'll have to blow up this whole place and return to a Unix-based employer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem related to DNS. Seems like you have 2 Domaincontrollers which can't reach each other. 
One DC updated his A records and tries to tell that your other DC which is not reachable.
Check if the A records in your DNS Lookupzone point to your actual DC.
Did you changed the IPs of the DCs in the past?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822053

It sounds like the RPC server is unavailable.  On the server having issues make sure the “Preferred DNS server” is pointed to your Domain Controller.